# How can I remove the first whitespace of every line of a file?

Tags: bash, grep, text-processing, sed, text

I have a file that looks like

```
SPT-CL J0000-5748 J000106.23-574536.8   0.275980 -57.760231 0.7554 0.0003 template 1
SPT-CL J0000-5748 J000049.27-574637.3   0.205320 -57.777050 0.7018 0.0002 template 1
SPT-CL J0000-5748 J000059.24-574759.6   0.246850 -57.799889 0.7059 0.0002 template 1
SPT-CL J0000-5748 J000107.36-574648.7   0.280680 -57.780209 0.6981 0.0002 template 1
```

for a few thousand lines. I need all of the `SPT-CL J0000-5748` turned into `SPT-CLJ0000-5748`. How can I do this very quickly via `bash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed 's/ //' file > newfile
```

or, if you want the changes to be made directly to the original file, you can use the `-i` command line flag - either along with a backup file

```
sed -i.bak 's/ //' file
```

or without creating a backup if you prefer

```
sed -i 's/ //' file
```

Comment: where in this expression is it specified that I only want to remove the whitespace between `SPT-CL` and `J0000-5748`?

Comment: The `-i.bak` option creates a backup copy of the original file before modifying it. This behaviour might be helpful or not, but you should at least mention this and offer the alternative option without backup (`-i`) IMHO.

Comment: @jphollowed `sed` by default only replaces the first match on every line. You would have to add the "global" flag to make it replace every match in a line.

Comment: @jphollowed it removes the *first* whitespace in each line, as per your question's title: if your file contains lines for which the first whitespace is not the one between `SPT-CL` and `J0000-5748` then that's easy enough to handle - but a good general principle IMHO is to use the *simplest* expression that does what you need